# Unable to Use Google Apps Script Library in Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries

I have an internal editor add-on that utilizes a library, both of which were created and developed in the same Shared Drive. After publishing the add-on, it does not recognize the library, and the `onOpen()` function throws an error when a document is opened/refreshed:

> Library with identifier MyLibrary is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

When testing the add-on from Run > Test as add-on there's no issue. I have tried removing and re-adding the library in Resources > Libraries with no luck. Development Mode is off. Nothing I have read in the documentation on [libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#using_a_library) or [collaborating](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating#collaborating_with_shared_drives) gives any indication as to what the problem could be.

Is there something I am missing here w/r/t publishing add-ons with libraries or housing them in Shared Drives? Could the Shared Drive be causing an issue with read access?

Comment: Compiled a list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63907324/

Answer (score 0):

1. Try sharing the library to anywone on the web with the link
2. If you are using the default runtime (Chrome V8) if you aren't using unsupported features by the old runtime, disable it, otherwise try first this creating a "mcve" / demo add-on

Related

- [Can I use in Google Apps Scripts a defined Class in a library with ES6 (V8)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60456303/1595451)
- [Library with identifier QUnit is missing - G Suite for Education Account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63798208/1595451)