# Defining a Global Variable from Library Object

Tags: javascript, object, google-sheets, google-apps-script, shared-libraries

I seek to group GIDs and the SSID as properties of a "SheetIDs" object. The variables do not seem to be properly assigned when in the object. Could someone assist in finding the error? The library is `ccCode`.

##### ccCode Library:

```
const DashboardSSID = "TEMPSSID";
const DashboardSheetIDs = {SSID:"TEMPSSID"};
```

---

##### SpreadsheetCode:

```
//Working
//SpreadsheetCode
const DashboardSSID = ccCode.DashboardSSID;


//Not Working
//SpreadsheetCode
const DashboardSSID = ccCode.DashboardSheetIDs.SSID;
//SpreadsheetError
//TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SSID')
```

The last one throws the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SSID')

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the issue

Comment: Cooper, these are all the pertinent details.

To recreate, a library could have to be created named "ccCode" with the const DashboardSheetIDs defined.

Comment: The provided code doesn't reproduce the error message. What do I have to do to reproduce it?

Comment: It's you task to create a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the issue in the minimum code possible.  Often in the course of doing this I find that I will solve my own problem.  If this is something you can't do then this may not be for forum for you. -

Comment: The first code wouldn't work  either. `const DashboardSSID = "TEMPSSID";` wouldn't throw as error, but `DashboardSSID` is ``undefined.`` Try to log `DashboardSSID`. This is because https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459759/ (`const` declarations aren't passed to end users)

Comment: Thank you for helping resolve this. Your fix works.

Answer (score 0):

[Thank you TheMaster for answering the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78133226/defining-a-global-variable-from-library-object#comment137748469_78133226)

This is because const declarations aren't passed to end users as written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459759.

---

This was fixed by changing `const` to `var`.